# How can I reduce the loss rate of G and D in GAN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm building a GAN using Tensorflow.

At first, I created a GAN that produces a 32x32 image.

Modified the model to add a layer to create a 128x128 image.

By the way, 32x32 GAN G, D loss value was ok, but the loss value is very high as the layer size and image size are increased.

I modified the layer and modified other hyper parameters to lower the loss, but it's still high.

I wonder how to reduce the loss of G and D.

```
import os.path
import numpy as np
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2DTranspose, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from keras.layers.core import Reshape, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU, ReLU
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import keras.backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import load_model
K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')

class Gan:
    def __init__(self,img_data):
        img_size = img_data.shape[1]
        channel = img_data.shape[3] if len(img_data.shape) >= 4 else 1

        self.img_data = img_data
        self.input_shape = (img_size,img_size,channel)

        self.img_rows = img_size
        self.img_cols = img_size
        self.channel = channel
        self.noise_size = 128

        self.create_d()
        self.create_g()

        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0008)
        self.D.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0004)
        self.D.trainable = False
        self.AM = Sequential()
        self.AM.add(self.G)
        self.AM.add(self.D)
        self.AM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer)

    def create_g(self):
        self.G = Sequential()
        dropout = 0.4

        self.G.add(Dense(8 * 8 * 1024, input_dim=self.noise_size))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.G.add(Reshape((8, 8, 1024)))
        self.G.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(512, 5, strides=2, padding ='same'))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, 5, strides=2, padding ='same'))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, 5, strides=2, padding ='same'))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, 5, strides=2, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(self.channel, 5, strides =1,padding='same'))
        self.G.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
        self.G.summary()
        return self.G

    def create_d(self):
        self.D = Sequential()
        dropout = 0.4
        self.D.add(Conv2D(64, 5, strides=2, input_shape=self.input_shape, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.D.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        self.D.add(Conv2D(128, 5, strides=2, input_shape=self.input_shape, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.D.add(Conv2D(256, 5, strides=2, input_shape=self.input_shape, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.D.add(Conv2D(512, 5, strides=1, input_shape=self.input_shape, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.D.add(Conv2D(1024, 5, strides=2, input_shape=self.input_shape, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.D.add(Flatten())
        self.D.add(Dense(1))
        self.D.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
        self.D.summary()
        return self.D


    def train(self, sess, batch_size=100):

        images_train = self.img_data[np.random.randint(0, self.img_data.shape[0], size=batch_size), :, :, :] #shape[0] -> image data의 숫자
        noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0,1.0, size=[batch_size,self.noise_size])
        images_fake = self.G.predict(noise)

        x = np.concatenate((images_train, images_fake))
        y = np.ones([2*batch_size,1])
        y[batch_size:,:] = 0
        self.D.trainable = True
        d_loss = self.D.train_on_batch(x,y)

        y = np.ones([batch_size,1])
        noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0,1.0,size=[batch_size,self.noise_size])
        self.D.trainable = False
        a_loss = self.AM.train_on_batch(noise,y)

        return d_loss, a_loss, images_fake

    def save_weigths(self):

        self.G.save_weights('gan_g_weights')
        self.D.save_weights('gan_d_weights')


    def load(self):
        if os.path.isfile('gan_g_weights'):
            self.G.load_weights('gan_g_weights')
            print("Load G from file")
        if os.path.isfile('gan_d_weights'):
            self.D.load_weights('gan_d_weights')
            print("Load D from file")

class faceData():
    def __init__(self):
        img_data_list = []
        images = os.listdir("data_rgb1")

        for path in images:
            img = Image.open("data_rgb1/" + path)
            img_data_list.append([np.array(img).astype('float32')])

        self.x_train = np.vstack(img_data_list) / 255.0
        print(self.x_train.shape)

dataset = faceData()
x_train =dataset.x_train

gan = Gan(x_train)
gan.load()

sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

epochs = 1000
sample_size = 10
batch_size = 50
train_per_epoch = x_train.shape[0] // batch_size



for epoch in range(0,epochs):
    total_d_loss = 0.0
    total_a_loss = 0.0
    imgs = None

    for batch in range(0, train_per_epoch):
        d_loss, a_loss, t_imgs = gan.train(batch_size)
        total_d_loss += d_loss
        total_a_loss += a_loss
        if imgs is None:
            imgs = t_imgs


    total_d_loss /= train_per_epoch
    total_a_loss /= train_per_epoch
    print("Epoch: {}, D Loss: {}, AM loss: {} " .format(epoch, total_d_loss, total_a_loss))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, sample_size, figsize = (sample_size, 1))
    if epoch == 999:
        for i in range(0, sample_size):
            ax[i].set_axis_off()
            ax[i].imshow(imgs[i].reshape((gan.img_rows, gan.img_cols, gan.channel)), interpolation='nearest');
            plt.savefig('result%d.png' % epoch)
        saver.save(sess, os.path.join('save', 'model_{}'.format(epoch)))


    plt.close('all')
    gan.save_weigths()
```

Result:

Epoch: 0, D Loss: 8.065221479096389, AM loss: 14.922738138189171

Epoch: 1, D Loss: 8.052544213793604, AM loss: 14.836829509831928

Epoch: 2, D Loss: 8.02602034776949, AM loss: 14.889192866794954

Epoch: 3, D Loss: 8.05762272074743, AM loss: 14.88101108667209

Epoch: 4, D Loss: 8.045719083795692, AM loss: 14.863829361000642

Epoch: 5, D Loss: 8.052135099614333, AM loss: 14.872829325913173

Epoch: 6, D Loss: 8.026918762226396, AM loss: 14.900647337666623

Epoch: 7, D Loss: 8.091860083759133, AM loss: 14.836829485626994

Epoch: 8, D Loss: 8.05686701130746, AM loss: 14.935828973799188

Epoch: 9, D Loss: 8.038368832641448, AM loss: 14.832738677862332

Epoch: 10, D Loss: 8.06173144016169, AM loss: 14.904738174477204

Epoch: 11, D Loss: 8.032495556749064, AM loss: 14.926010857983893 
.
.
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the beatiful world of training a GAN. It is not an easy task yet not impossible. I cannot tell what the problems are just by looking at the loss from the first 10 epochs.

I **highly** recommend you to take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@utk.is.here/keep-calm-and-train-a-gan-pitfalls-and-tips-on-training-generative-adversarial-networks-edd529764aa9). You are probably having trouble since the equilibrium must have been broken when you added more layers.

Some tips recommended in the article are:

1. Look at the gradients.
2. Perform a pretraining.
3. Do not use hard labels.

Some personal tips are: add batch normalization at the generator. Do not use dense layers in the generator.

Good luck, have fun and please! Post some of the images you are generating I am very curious!

Comment: Really Thanks for your reply.
now i changed epoch, but loss is almost same. 
I read article and i have some guess. 
what is mean hard labels?

Comment: It means that, in the training of the discriminator, instead of labeling as 1 or 0 the fake/real images, we put soft labels, numbers between 1 and 0.9 or  between 0 and 0.1 for some of the images.

Comment: I have one more thing I want to ask.
It is about the loss of generator and discriminator.
In my modified model, the loss of generator is increasing and the loss value of discriminator is 0.11 ~ 0.15. Is this correct?
I wonder if the loss of the generator and the loss of the discriminator should be good models.
Example: A good model when G loss is high and D loss is low?

Comment: Hmmm. The convergence of a GAN is something very hard to achieve. In your case. It looks as if the discriminator is too 'smart' or the generator too 'dumb'. You should check how the generated images vary over the epochs and do an early stop when both losses are considerably low and the generated images have good quality and make sense for your purpose! From a quick search I found this: https://towardsdatascience.com/10-lessons-i-learned-training-generative-adversarial-networks-gans-for-a-year-c9071159628. Might be helpful!